# Run batch script in windows scheduler with jar

Tags: java, batch-file, windows-10, scheduler

I am running the batch file from windows scheduler , when I execute batch file directly it works, but when added in scheduler , it is not running. 
 Run.bat contains

```
java -cp D:\Test_Automation\LocalExecutable\TestAutomation-1.0-fat-tests.jar my.com.testauto.TestRunner
```

Should I set anything in batch file.

Comment: Try with the full path of the java instead of only the `java` command. May be problem with the path variable.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, Scheduled tasks are not visible to the user, if you were expecting something to happen on screen, then that is one of the reasons you might think it did not happen. I am not able to see what your Java program is built to do. If however it is a path issue, there are manual ways and automated ways. here are some examples.

Either put the full path of the java instance into the batch file.

```
c:\apps\jdk\bin\java.exe -cp D:\Test_Automation\LocalExecutable\TestAutomation-1.0-fat-tests.jar my.com.testauto.TestRunner
```

or if you are unsure of the location of `java`, run a loop to find it for you.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where /r c:\ java.exe') do set "fnd=%%~a" & goto init
:init
"%fnd" -cp D:\Test_Automation\LocalExecutable\TestAutomation-1.0-fat-tests.jar my.com.testauto.TestRunner
```